# XHR works on localhost server but not on my static IP on IIS

Tags: html, iis, xmlhttprequest, ip, windows-server-2012-r2

I am using IIS on my Windows Server 2012 R2 program. I have a static IP, and I've binded it to a port and enabled port forwarding so it is accessible online. Here's the thing, on localhost my XHR request produces the desired output. But when I search my static IP in the URL, and attempt the request, it does not produce anything. Here are the files:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The XMLHttpRequest Object</h1>

<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Request data</button>

<p id="demo"></p>


<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "demo_get.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And here's my desired output "demo_get.txt":

```html
<p>This Content was requested using the GET method.</p>
```

So can someone please guide me in making my XHR request functional when I enter my Static IP into the url? Thanks.

Comment: You are experiencing CORS problem maybe

Comment: @VladoPandžić both files are from the same directory, would it still be a CORS issue? Wouldn't it be from the same origin?

Comment: Additionally, on the Developer Tools, on localhost, I get successful (200) request. But when I use my IP url, no request is made.

Comment: First, learn what is IIS site binding, https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html Then trace what request is exactly sent to IIS by your code (browser developer tool or Telerik Fiddler). Add what you observed as part of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by others, I went into the Developer Tools and found that no request was being sent on the Network Tab. So, I investigated my security settings on my local intranet. I enabled some settings, and that's all it took for the XHR requests to function. Thank you everyone for your input!